# Set date in datepicker jquery from date php, strange values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I'm working with datepicker as follows:

```
<?php 

$sql="SELECT date FROM user WHERE id='$id_p' ;";
$result= query($sql);
/*Code for query in postgresql */

$date1=date_create($row['date']);
$date2=date_format($date1, 'd/m/Y');
$date3=$row['date'];
?>

<div class="form-group ">
    <label>Date *</label><br>
    <input id="date1" type="text" class="form-control required" >
    <input type="hidden" id="date3" name="datealt">
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $("#fechaV").datepicker({
        firstDay:1,
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié;', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        altFormat:'yy/mm/dd'          
    });
});

var date1=<?php echo $date2;?>;
var date3=<?php echo $date3;?>;
console.log(date1);
console.log(date3);
$("#date1").attr("value", date1);
$('#date3').attr("value",date3);
</script>
```

My problem is that when printing the dates in the script, it takes strange values, I can notice it when printing in the console and set the datepicker. However, on seeing the code portion, I can see these have the correct value.

That is, in my code, the variables take the values:

```
var date1=01/01/2016;
var date3=2016-01-01;
```

In the console.log:

```
0.000496031746031746
2014
```

What is wrong?

PD: probably missing segments of code or some names do not match, but it was time to transcribe the code to write the problem. Sorry for my english level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first:

```
var date1="<?php echo $date2;?>";
var date3="<?php echo $date3;?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your vars between quotes:

```
var date1 = '<?php echo $date2;?>';
var date3 = '<?php echo $date3;?>';
```

Comment: This is the what I said :)

Comment: You're right, my bad, saw it too late, please accept the other answer if it works.

Comment: no problem. 4 minutes for can accept. Btw... ' ' and " " works the same way